# Reading files with a for-loop in java

Tags: java, file, for-loop

I got this annoyed problem with a simple for cycle. This is the schema of my program

```
public static void methodA(File a, File b){
      //procedure
}

Public static void readFiles(String a){

   File folder = new File(a);
   File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.lenght-1; i++) 
    {

        if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
        {
            readFile(listOfFiles[i].getPath());
        }
        else
        {
            methodA(listOfFiles[i],listOfFiles[i+1])
        }
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

   String path = new String("Path to global folder");
   readFile(path);

}
```

The problem is, when I got inside the first folder from version 2 to 3 I'm having this message error (the number of files- only files- is equal to 5):

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException**

But if I do something like this: **for (int i = 3; i < listOfFiles.lenght-1; i++)** the program works without any problem, and the same is happening with some files inside other folders.

In every folder there are at least 3 files (only files).

What can be happening?, I also tried doing the debug to try to understand the problem but without any success.

Comment: Full stack trace plz. And more code. Without that I can only say that something is null...

Comment: I very much doubt it works with that change.

Comment: Actually it works, that is why I have decided to write this question. Making the for iterate only 1 step specific for that couple of file (3 and 4) I do not have any problem. The strange is that with other folders the NullPointer is indicated in different position. For this example I had to do this : for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.lenght-2; i++) and then for (int i = 3; i < listOfFiles.lenght-1; i++), only in this way I could have the results that I need.

Comment: I think he was referencing the fact that the code you posted won't compile-- you spelled `length` wrong. In the future, it's better to copy/paste your code directly instead of retyping it. Also, post the full stack trace.

Comment: Also, the brackets in the call to methodA are not balanced (three opening brackets and only one closing). Like kevensa5 says, copy-paste would probably be your friend.

Answer (score 1):

listFiles is only valid for Folders. If you use listFiles on a File instead of a Folder, it will return `null`.

Then, `listOfFiles.lenght` throws a NPE.

Flip your If-Cases.